# How can merge data from a simple List as a part of a Map parameter?

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dictionary, dart

I'm just starting with Flutter and I'm struggling with lists and maps, so if anyone mind to help it would be great!

What I is to make a simple list like

`['Johh', 'Will', 'Mary']`

to a **List<Map<String, Object>>** like

```
{'Name': 'John', 'Aplication' : Datetime.now()},
{'Name': 'Will', 'Aplication' : Datetime.now()},
{'Name': 'Mary', 'Aplication' : Datetime.now()}
```

I've read so many forums but still didn't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option for converting a list to a list of Map<String, object>

```
void main() async {
  List data = ['Johh', 'Will', 'Mary'];
  
  var newData = data.map((val) {
    return {'name': val, 'application': DateTime.now()};
  }).toList();
  
  print(newData);
}
```

I recommend checking out https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_map.htm it is a good source of information and easy to follow.

Comment: It works just as supposed to be. Thanks!